# List functions returning no resources

Tags: google-shopping-api, google-shopping

I have been using the online testing tool, and C# to experiment with the Google Shopping APIs. I added Products and Orders with the online utility, and am able to use the `Products.get` and the `Orders.get` functions to retrieve them, both with the online utility and in C#. But when I use list functions, no data is returned and no error is occurrs; `resources[]` is always `null`. I have tried passing parameters that should include items, and not passing parameters without success. I'm not sure how to correct this, or if I'm doing something wrong.

The first two calls to `Get` work, the third call to `List` returns no resources:

`var product1 = await service.Products.Get(MerchantID, "online:en:US:261-H5MS").ExecuteAsync();`

`var product2 = await service.Products.Get(MerchantID, "online:en:US:261-LMS3").ExecuteAsync();`

`var products = await service.Products.List(MerchantID).ExecuteAsync();`

Return from `List`:

`{
 "kind": "content#productsListResponse"
}`

Comment: Please provide more information. Answers to your question will be of higher quality if you provide all relevant code, stack traces, and errors. If you'd prefer to not share the specifics of your code, coding up a general, toy example that replicates the error works too.

Answer (score 0):

I found the `IncludeInvalidInsertedItems` boolean in the online utility. If I set that to `true`, then it returns my apparently invalid products.

Now my question is, how do I include that in my call in C#?

`var products = await service.Products.List(MerchantID).ExecuteAsync();`

There is no overload to `List` allowing me to add options.